# How to convert 'wchar_t *' to 'const char *'

Tags: c++, mfc

How can I convert '`wchar_t` *' to '`const char *`' ?

using C++ MFC VS2010.

*Thank you.*

Comment: If it's MFC, do you really have a CString? I'm a few versions out-of-date, but they used have a cast operator to LPCSTR on the CString types that would do the conversion for you. You may even be able to just construct a CStringA from the wide string and have it convert it for you.

Comment: The technical answer to this question is rarely useful in isolation. _Why_ do you need to do this? E.g. if it's to pass a pointer through a callback interface, a straightforward cast is OK.

Comment: I need to fill structure with CHAR  Name[256]; but I've got wchar_t * instead of char* .

Comment: OK - which structure? Is there really not a wide-string version of that structure and API you can use instead? You really shouldn't be using CHARs if you can avoid it - you'll hit problems with internationalization etc.

Comment: I'm sure I need to use exactly chars there because of compatibility

Comment: Well, whatever is going to use that `Name` will have some expectations. In fact, a very common expection is that you won't pass 大日本帝国. `CHAR[256]` means 8x256 bits, surely there's more you know about it.

Answer (score 7):

As the question is about MFC, I would suggest the following:

```
CStringA a = "Test";
CStringW w = L"Test";
a = CStringA(w);
w = CStringW(a);
```

I typically need the following conversions:

```
CString t = _T("Test"); // depends on TCHAR type
a = CStringA(t); // does not depend on TCHAR type
w = CStringW(t);
```

CStringW and CStringA have operators LPCWSTR and LPCSTR respectivelly.