# How to convert Wchar_t* to const char*

Tags: c++, wchar

I am a kind of new for c++ , while working on the windows CE .net compact application

while trying to write hexa datas to a file

```
CString dataBlock1;
dataBlock1 = "";

CString temp;
for(int i = 0; i < rLen; i++)
{
temp.Format(L"%02X ",rec[i]);
dataBlock1 += temp;

}

std::ofstream out(file);
```

I am getting this error can not convert parameter 1 from wchar * to const char* 
on while using the below write function to write hexa datas to a file

```
out.write(myReader.dataBlock1.GetBuffer(),myReader.dataBlock1.GetLength());
```

how can we convert wchar_* to const char*  to make the write function work.

Thanks.

Comment: [How to convert 'wchar_t *' to 'const char *'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835119/how-to-convert-wchar-t-to-const-char). Not only is it a duplicate question, but also using `CString`, and has the exact same title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `wcstombs` function, reference [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/wcstombs).

Comment: is there any equivalent in win32?

Answer (score 1):

Windows has a set of classes and functions that take wchar_t, which is text stored as UTF-16, and char, which is text stored in your ANSI character set. If you have pointer to wchar_t you either need to use an appropriate class or function that accepts wchar_t, or you need to convert the data to your ANSI character set.

In this case, you want the wchar_t variant of ofstream, wofstream.